# What is non-lazy initialization?

Tags: java, classloader, lazy-initialization

I am sure that everyone knows the following implementation of Singleton pattern:

```
public class Singleton {

private static volatile Singleton instance;

private Singleton(){}

public static Singleton getInstance() {

    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (Singleton.instance){
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
        }
    }

    return instance;
}}
```

I know that it is an implementation accordingly to lazy initialization.
But Java ClassLoader loads classes in a lazy mode.

How is it possible for any object to be not lazily initialized?
Regardless an object realization an instance is created only when you use word 'new' or call a factory method.

What is non-lazily class loading?

Comment: I don't know the "following implementation of Singleton pattern". The code you have posted is broken and will throw a NullPointerException in 99.999% of the cases on line `synchronized (Singleton.instance)`.

Comment: Are you asking about class "loading" or "initialization"?  Your title says one, your final question says the other.  They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Non-lazy loading would instantiate `instance` immediately when the class is loaded, rather than waiting until the first call to `getInstance()`.

```
public class Singleton {
    private static volatile Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

If the class is loaded but nobody ever calls `getInstance()` it wastes time and memory creating an object that is never used.